# Анализатор кода PHP?

Tags: php

Существует ли анализатор кода PHP, который может показать связи в коде?

Comment: Да, например phpcallgraph.

Answer (score 1):

Мы используем [PHP Depend](https://pdepend.org/download/index.html). На Jenkins его xml результаты с помощью JDepend плагина отображаем.

Но он вроде может и сам по себе вполне наглядные результаты [генерировать](https://habrahabr.ru/post/80110/).

Это если вам нужен просто анализ зависимостей. А для callgraph я люблю использовать xdebug profiler с визуализацией в kcachegrind.